# How to get videos folder?

Tags: java, android

I am working on a video player app. I have two fragments: one is `AllVideolist` fragment and the other one is `Videos` folders fragment. The AllVideoList`enter code here` fragment is working fine, but I don't know how to show get all videos folder.

This is my `MainActivity.java` code.

MainActivity.java

```
public ArrayList<videoFiles> getAllVideos(Context context) {
    ArrayList<videoFiles> tempArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String [] projection = {
            MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION

    };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    if (cursor!= null){
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){


            String id =cursor.getString(0);
            String path =cursor.getString(1);
            String title =cursor.getString(2);
            String fileName =cursor.getString(3);
            String size =cursor.getString(4);
            String dateAdded =cursor.getString(5);
            String duration =cursor.getString(6);

            int durationa = Integer.parseInt(duration);

            String duration_formet;
            int sec = (durationa/1000)%60;
            int min = (durationa/(1000*60))%60;
            int hours = durationa/(1000*60*60);

            if (hours == 0){
                duration_formet = String.valueOf(min).concat(":" .concat(String.format(Locale.UK, "%02d",sec)));
            }else {
                duration_formet = String.valueOf(hours).concat(":" .concat(String.format(Locale.UK, "%02d",min).concat(":" .concat(String.format(Locale.UK, "%02d",sec)))));

            }

            videoFiles videoFiles = new videoFiles(id, path, title,fileName,size, dateAdded,duration_formet);
            Log.d("path", path);
            tempArrayList.add(videoFiles);

        }
        cursor.close();
    }
        return tempArrayList;
}
```

I craete this model class.
VideoFiles.java

```
public class videoFiles {


    ///------------------MODEL CLASS ---------------

  private String id;
  private String path;
  private String title;
  private String fileName;
  private String size;
  private String dateAdded;
  private String duration;

    public videoFiles(String id, String path, String title, String fileName, String size, String dateAdded, String duration) {
        this.id = id;
        this.path = path;
        this.title = title;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.size = size;
        this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
        this.duration = duration;


    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getDateAdded() {
        return dateAdded;
    }

    public void setDateAdded(String dateAdded) {
        this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
```

This is folder Adapter.

FolderAdapter.java

```
 public class FolderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FolderAdapter.folderViewHolder> {
        View view;
        Context context;
        private ArrayList<videoFiles> folderList;
    
    
        public FolderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<videoFiles> folderList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.folderList = folderList;
    
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public FolderAdapter.folderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.foldeitems, parent, false);
            return new folderViewHolder(view);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FolderAdapter.folderViewHolder holder, int position) {
                holder.folderName.setText(folderList.get(position).getPath());
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return folderList.size();
        }
    
        public class folderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView folderName;
            public folderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                folderName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foldername);
    
            }
        }
    }
```

This is main foledr fragment. I want to show videos in folder by folder

```
FoldeFragment.java


public class FolderFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;


    public FolderFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_folder, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.folderRecylerView);


      
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a minimum, reproducible example of your issue? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service; we need a specific question to give a specific answer. If you post what you've tried and how it's not working, we'd be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "videos folder" in Android. There are number of default locations for videos, but they vary from device to device. Devices that have expandable memory often have video storage defaults that don't exist on non-expandable devices. User are not obliged to put video files in these default locations, anyway.

If you want to get a list of all directories that contain video files, you'll either need to implement some sort of search/index operation yourself, or use the built-in media database. You should be able to enumerate the list of videos from the database, and extract the unique folder names.

For what it's worth, I answered a similar question here:

[How to show only videos folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003469/how-to-show-only-videos-folder)

Comment: Sir, Can you write some example code for me? Because I am finding solution for the last 3 days. please sir.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've only used the Android media database for audio. Is there not an open-source video app or file manager you can look at for inspiration? Good luck.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Thank you